# How to send E-mail through JCL with 2 line title?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

Good afternoon,
I have a requirement that consists of sending an e-mail from a batch job which has a title which occupies 2 lines. Two lines named TITLE1 and TITLE2 were used in one of the attempts but it didn't work.
Are there any suggestions? I've visited several forums but with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: JCL has not a lot to do with it. It will let the system know which program to run and the resources required. So what program are you trying to execute? What control statements have you used? What control statements does the documentation for that program allow?

Comment: Could try putting the tittle on one line with the New-Line Char (x15) between the 2 tittles. i.e `TITTLE 1`<new-line char>`TITTLE 2`. Might work ???

Comment: By title do you mean subject? I wasn't aware that SMTP mail supported multi-line subjects. If 'title' is simply part of the email body then that should be easily achievable.

Comment: Can you share what you tried (JCL, utilities, etc.) as well as a format of the output you are expecting?

Comment: Are you certain that multi-line subjects are even possible? My reading of the RFC 2822 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) is that there is only one logical line.